# Python - how to convert a list with tuples into a dictonary with two values

Tags: python, list

iam searching for a small and easy possibility to convert a list with tuples into a dictonary which has one key and two values.
When possible with no external libary.

```
l1 = ["a","b","c"]
l2 = [1, 2, 3]
l3 = [11,22,33]

mylist = list(zip(l1, l2, l3))

**output:**
[('a', 1, 11), ('b', 2, 22), ('c', 3, 33)]

**i tried:**
mydict = {}
mydict = dict(mylist)

**Error:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 8, in <module>
    dictonary = dict(mylist)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required

**the solution should look like:**
 {'a': (1, 11),'b': (2, 22),'c': (3, 33)} or
 {'a': [1, 11],'b': [2, 22],'c': [3, 33]}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `dictionary comprehension` should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough, nesting the `zip` to make sure you call the `dict` constructor with an iterable over *pairs*:

```
l1 = ["a","b","c"]
l2 = [1, 2, 3]
l3 = [11,22,33]

dct = dict(zip(l1, zip(l2, l3)))
# {'a': (1, 11), 'b': (2, 22), 'c': (3, 33)}
```

Or, using a `dict` comprehension and starting from your intermediate list of triplets (but works for iterables of any length > 0):

```
dct = {h: t for h, *t in mylist}
# {'a': [1, 11], 'b': [2, 22], 'c': [3, 33]}
```

Comment: ok, thanks, I wasnt aware that zip can also handle a zip object as input.

Comment: Yup, `zip` can take any iterable.